# Failed to renew SSL certificates using Certbot's "dry-run" command

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, node.js, lets-encrypt, certbot

I was using apache for my website and created the SSL for Apache. Then for some reason, I have to change my server from Apache to Node.js. To do that I just copied the SSL certificates path from Apache’s Vhost file and pasted it in the configuration for Node.js.

It is now working fine. But then I got an email about "TLS-SNI-01" validation issue that says

> Action required: Let’s Encrypt certificate renewals

I open ssh to my VPS and updated the Certbot. But when I tried to renew the SSL certificates using dry-run command. I got an error that says “Unable to find a virtual host …”.

Is it still trying to change the apache’s virtual host files?

Because I have a web server for my domain which is listening on port 80 and 443. But the apache's vhost configuration files have been deleted.